# Validating more than 1 input

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble validating multiple inputs onsubmit.

Validation (and also clearing the validation error onkeyup when that input is edited) is working for the first input only.

I assume you can't have numerous `if` statements laid out like I have, but I can't work out the way it should be written in order to validate all 3 inputs onsubmit. Should they be separate functions? I tried multiple onsubmit functions but again that didn't work.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fps0xfzu/)

JS

```
function contactForm() {
    var theForm = document.forms.contact;

    var errorUsername = document.getElementById('username-error');
    var usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');

    var errorPassword = document.getElementById('password-error');  
    var passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');

    var errorEmail = document.getElementById('email-error');
    var emailInput = document.getElementById('email');

    //clear validation error from usernameInput
    theForm.onkeyup = function() {
        if (usernameInput.value.length === 0) return;
            errorUsername.style.display = 'none';
            usernameInput.className = 'form__input rounded-4';
        };

    theForm.onsubmit = function(){
        //Check for username
    if (usernameInput.value.length === 0) {
            errorUsername.style.display = 'block';
            usernameInput.className = 'form__input form__input--red rounded-4';
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        };

        //Check for password
        if (passwordInput.value.length === 0) {
            errorPassword.style.display = 'block';
            passwordInput.className = 'form__input form__input--red rounded-4';
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        };

        //Check for email
        if (emailInput.value.length === 0) {
            errorEmail.style.display = 'block';
            emailInput.className = 'form__input form__input--red rounded-4';
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        };

    };  

};
contactForm();
```

HTML

```
<form name="contact" action="#" novalidate>
            <div class="input__holder">
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form__input rounded-4" placeholder="Username">
                <div id="username-error" class="input__error">!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="input__holder">
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form__input rounded-4" placeholder="Password">
                <div id="password-error" class="input__error">!</div>               
            </div>      
            <div class="input__holder">     
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form__input rounded-4" placeholder="E-mail">
                <div id="email-error" class="input__error">!</div>              
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="" class="submit-button rounded-4">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Don't return your true or false value from the onsubmit handler until you're ready to do so. Validate everything, then return your boolean value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify your flow in the if statement a bit.

Set a flag for valid (initially `true`), then in each condition, modify the flag to be `false` if it fails validation.  Then return the flag once at the end of the if condition.

This way, all elements can get the relevant class assigned to them if they are not valid.

NOTE: I've improved the code to "reset" the error states, in case a user submits - has 2 errors, fixes one - so that the "Fixed" one will not still have the error state.

```
theForm.onsubmit = function() {
    // Set initial "valid" state flag
    var valid = true;

    // reset all "error" styles / messages
    errorUsername.style.display = 'none';
    usernameInput.className = 'form__input rounded-4';

    errorPassword.style.display = 'none';
    passwordInput.className = 'form__input rounded-4';

    errorEmail.style.display = 'none';
    emailInput.className = 'form__input rounded-4';

    // Now check the form and assign error styles as appropriate
    //Check for username
    if (usernameInput.value.length === 0) {
        errorUsername.style.display = 'block';
        usernameInput.className = 'form__input form__input--red rounded-4';
        valid = false;
    } 

    //Check for password
    if (passwordInput.value.length === 0) {
        errorPassword.style.display = 'block';
        passwordInput.className = 'form__input form__input--red rounded-4';
        valid = false;
    }

    //Check for email
    if (emailInput.value.length === 0) {
        errorEmail.style.display = 'block';
        emailInput.className = 'form__input form__input--red rounded-4';
        valid = false;
    }  

    return valid;
};
```

Comment: the explanation you gave is probably more helpful than the code fix, as you can tell I'm learning js still and along with your in code comments it just makes sense to me now, really appreciate the help. it's often a worry I'll get a solution but won't really understand :)

Comment: Also the fix you added I didn't even consider myself, thank you

Comment: Thanks.   I like to provide both - so the "concept" is explained (and the reasoning), but also you can see it "in practice" in the code.  Sometimes the explanation doesn't quite do it, and sometimes the code can be confusing!